# Cast (?) of a pointer not assigned to lvalue

Tags: c, pointers, casting

I am dealing with other people's code which often has lines like this...

```
aRES someFunction(void* aHandle)
{
    (void)aHandle;
    return RES_OK;
}
```

What does the line:

```
(void)aHandle;
```

do? Comments suggest it suppresses an error - does/could it?

Comment: Is it to make the compiler think that argument was "used"?

Comment: Thanks both - I suppose that could be it